# XQuery when a node doesn't exist

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

In the following XQuery syntax, I've added in the last table with a CROSS APPLY, and it seems to filter out some records.  It would seem that this is the case because the node defined is optional.  I thought that my code would result in the equivalent of a LEFT OUTER JOIN, however it is behaving like an INNER.

```
FROM   
      xxx_XML CROSS APPLY 
      XmlData.nodes('/reports/report/xxx-report') AS xxx(pref) CROSS APPLY
      pref.nodes('summary') AS Summary(sref) CROSS APPLY
      pref.nodes('data/proj-title/title-code') AS Title(tref)
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that my code would result in
>   the equivalent of a LEFT OUTER JOIN,
>   however it is behaving like an INNER.

If you want [apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to behave like an outer join you could use `outer apply`.